# How to create/add an admin link using Shopify Admin API (Node.js / JavaScript) programatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

Using Shopify Api's i need to create a custom app using node.js / JavaScript that will create/add one admin link programmatically.

I have referred to the admin Api's but could not find any solution to this via Node.js / JavaScript.

**Links Referred: -**

```
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-an-admin-link-to-the-shopify-admin-with-app-extensions
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-admin-api
```

Below are the snapshots on creating admin links via portal, we want to add the same programatically using node js / javascript so the link values will be dynamic and not static.

[snapshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYu3I.png)

[snapshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy2lm.png)

[snapshot-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1tzk.png)

[snapshot-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJSVx.png)

Any help shall be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This snapshot looks for the embedded APP, this is the APP default homepage or any other page accessed in Shopify backend, once you create an embedded APP.

Comment: Thanks Onkar! Could you please help me a link / reference for the api's to achieve the said above using node / javascript?

Comment: I think these are links that are attached to a limited section into the backend and you can't add from code, you need to register them into the APP backend when you configuring the APP.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If i use the dashboard i.e. without coding https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-an-admin-link-to-the-shopify-admin-with-app-extensions in order details screen is it possible to update [Shopify Order Number] in the link to navigate?

Comment: Nopes, you can't update the data that is added to the link, It will be added by the Shopify end and it is according to a page that you navigate. like if you are on a single order page it embeds the id of the order to link automatically.